# global pointer value lost. 2 c files

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables

I'm making trie using 3 files: speller.c is the main file, dictionary.c contains functions & global root trie pointer, dictionary.h declares a dictionary's functions. 
Having problems with global root pointer value lost, after function load complete in dictionary.c.

speller.c

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    // load dictionary
    char* dictionary = TMPDICT;

    bool loaded = load(dictionary);

    // abort if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    //next I need to call check function, but root value is missing here

}
```

dictionary.c

```
typedef struct TrieNode
    {
      struct TrieNode **children;
      bool is_word;
    } TrieNode;
struct TrieNode * root;


struct TrieNode *create_trienode(char c, struct TrieNode *parent);
bool load(const char* dictionary)
    {

        FILE * file = fopen(dictionary, "r"); 
        if (file == NULL) 
        {
            printf("trie: No such file(dictionary)\n"); 
            return 1;
        }

        struct TrieNode *root = create_trienode(' ', NULL);
        struct TrieNode *ptr = root; 
        int character;
        int converted;
        int buffer;

        //This handles if file does not end with a newline
        character = fgetc(file);
        buffer = fgetc(file);

        while(character != EOF)
        {
            character = tolower(character);
            if (character == 10) // if newline, start new word read
            {

            }
            else 
            if(isalpha(character))
            {
                converted = character - 'a'; 
                if(ptr->children[converted] == NULL)
                {
                    ptr->children[converted] = create_trienode(character, ptr); 
                }
            ptr = ptr->children[converted]; 
            }


        if (character == SLASHNUM) //if backslash
        {
            if(ptr->children[SLASH_TMP] == NULL)
            {
                ptr->children[SLASH_TMP] = create_trienode(character, ptr);
            }
            ptr = ptr->children[SLASH_TMP];
        }

        if(ptr != root && (!(character == SLASHNUM  || isalpha(character)) || buffer == EOF)) 
        {
            ptr->is_word = true;
            ptr = root;
            word_count++;
        }

          character = buffer;
          buffer = fgetc(file);
        }

       return true; 
    }


struct TrieNode *create_trienode(char c, struct TrieNode *parent)
{
    struct TrieNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct TrieNode));
    node->children = malloc(ALPHABET_SIZE * sizeof(struct TrieNode*));
    node->is_word=false;

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
    {
        node->children[i] = NULL;
    }

    return node; 
}
```

gdb

```
Breakpoint 1, load (dictionary=0x80489c4 "tmpDict") at dictionary.c:100
100     character = fgetc(file);
(gdb) info locals
file = 0x804b008
root = 0x804b170
ptr = 0x804b170
character = 1267019363
converted = 262929407
buffer = 1266804984
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff0d4) at speller.c:40
$1 = (struct TrieNode *) 0x0
(gdb)
```

How can I make root visible in speller.c? Also in the task said that I can't change speller.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code defines `root` twice, with the definition local to `load()` shadowing the global definition.

This line

```
struct TrieNode *root = create_trienode(' ', NULL);
```

defines `root` locally and assigns the result of `create_trienode()` to this local definition of `root`.

From this local definition of `root` on, the globally defined `root` is shadowed by the local one, and not accessible any more.

To fix this change this:

```
    struct TrieNode *root = create_trienode(' ', NULL);
    struct TrieNode *ptr = root;
```

to

```
    struct TrieNode *ptr= create_trienode(' ', NULL);
    root = ptr;
```

Comment: This answer __is__ correct. Why's the downvote? (+1 from my side)

Answer (score 5):

In general, you need to declare the `root` as `extern` in the *dictionary.h* file and include that header file in *speller.c*.

This way, `root` will be available to the translation unit *spleller.c*. Next, you can make use of `root` inside *speller.c* just like any other local variable (which is *defined* in that file itself).

---

[As rightly pointed by [Mr. alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) in below comment]

The issue *here* is the definition of the *local* `root` variable

```
 struct TrieNode *root = create_trienode(' ', NULL);
```

inside the `load()` function actually *shadows* the global `root`

```
struct TrieNode * root;`
```

and thus, the global `root` never get updated.

Related, from `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the *inner scope*) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the *outer scope*). **Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

Comment: Finally 1+ for quoting the Standard.